# Why did the css displayed different style in different browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in page .

```
 <ul class="editorial-tabs-menu  menu">
   <li class="first"><a href="#" class="selected">Home
     <span></span>
    </a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Links</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#analyzes">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#ux">Link2</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I use this css for it:

```
.editorial-tabs-menu li a
{
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg,#F0F8FF,#fff);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#F0F8FF),to(#fff));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F0F8FF',endColorstr='#fff');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#F0F8FF, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF, GradientType=0)";
padding: 3px 0;
width: 83px;
text-align: center;
color: #666;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'B Nazanin',Tahoma,Arial;
position: relative;
/*border-bottom: none;*/
}

.editorial-tabs-menu li a:hover, .editorial-tabs-menu li .selected
{
    color: #FFF;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #095283, rgb(31, 108, 162)) repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0,0% 100%,from(#095283),to( rgb(31, 108, 162)));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#095283',endColorstr=' rgb(31, 108, 162)');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#095283, endColorstr='rgb(31, 108, 162)', GradientType=0)";
    border-color: #095283;
}

.menu ul li
{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li
{
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a
{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;*/
}
```

I want to set   `background: none;` for submenu when `hover`.

I set this css

```
.menu ul li a:hover
    {
        background: none;
        color: #095283;
    }
```

but it get css `.editorial-tabs-menu li a:hover` when submenu hover.

when i change this css to `background: red;` , it is red in chrom but it get css `.editorial-tabs-menu li a:hover` in ie and mozila.

Comment: Where in your stylesheet have you put `.menu ul li a:hover`? If it's before then it will be overridden by the CSS lower down the style sheet.

Comment: @slacker add the jsfiddle-link as a comment, not as an edit.

Comment: @AlexLynham : Thnaks, but it is after then .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can postfix your style definition with `!important` to ensure it overrides any other definitions. For example you could write in your css:

```
a:hover{background-color: #f00 !important;}
```

Which would match all a tags of the document...

This jsFiddle illustrates this, http://jsfiddle.net/GG2Da/1 - try removing the `!important` from the css and see what happens.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use this, it is work in Firefox and chrom but don't work in IE :(

Comment: try adding to your css: a{background:none !important;}

Comment: I remove `!important` from `.editorial-tabs-menu li a:hover` and add ` .menu ul li a:hover{
            background: none !important;}` , it is work in Firefox and chrom but don't work in IE.

Comment: press F12 in IE, and check that your browser and document modes are set to IE9

Comment: browser mode : IE9 , Document mode: IE8 standards.

Comment: the issue seems to be the filter: and -ms-filter selectors. If you remove these then your issue is resolved. But you will then have to find another way of applying a gradient to your links for IE. I suggest creating a button design, in Photoshop for example, and using that as the background for your links. This will ensure your links look the same on all browsers, and reduce the complexity/messiness of your CSS

Comment: Thanks a lot , I use `filter:none !important` for IE9  :)